# Converting hex file to binary file using arm compiler's 'fromelf'

Tags: cmake, arm

Under a linux machine I'm using ARMCompiler6.6.1 to generate an executable using some .c and .asm files. 
I'm also using cmake to build the target.

I have created the target say my_target.hex. It has a hex extension as that is the output format from the compiler. 
Now I need it to be a .bin file so I did some research and found out that this compiler has a tool called 'fromelf' which can convert a file from hex to binary.

I found that the syntax for the forelf is like this:
fromelf --bin --output=outfile.bin infile.hex

I'm running the 'fromelf' tool with cmake with ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND ran with the POST-BUILD option. Like this:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    TARGET my_target POST_BUILD
    COMMAND /opt/ARMCompiler6.6.1/bin/fromelf --bin path/to/target/my_target.elf --output path/to/generated/bin/file/my_target.bin 
    COMMENT "Converting binary file from elf"
)
```

After running this I was expecting to see a .bin file at the specified target. However instead of this I see 3 files:
text, mk_exceptiontable and mk_exceptiontable_ram.

That 'text' file looks like a binary file so I took it and renamed it to my_target.bin. Is that the right way to do it? Why am I getting that output and not some .bin file after the command? 
Thank you for reading!

Comment: "Why am I getting that output and not some .bin file after the command?" - CMake just executes command line which you pass in *COMMAND* option. Make sure, that the command's parameters refer to actual files. If the command needs to be executed from a specific directory, add appropriate *WORKING_DIRECTORY* option (by default, the command is executed in current build directory). Instead of adding this custom command, you may run your tool from the command line with the same parameters, and check resulted files.

Comment: The command doesn't need to be specified in some specific directory. It just needs the path to input file and another path to specify the desired path for the file which will get created. I will try what you said(running the command independently of cmake) and see the results.

Comment: why not build an elf from the start (which the toolchain may possible doing anyway) and then convert that into the various formats (intel hex, motorola srecord, binary memory image, etc)?  not that you cant easily get from intel hex to a binary image.  I would recommend you write the 30 lines of code to do the conversion yourself for educational purposes.